# Help with nested If statements that format a phone number based on country

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, development, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create a calculated column with nested if statements. Due to my users not wanting to format the phone number correctly I am creating this new column to take the phone number in the other column and format it for them. I need the format to be based of their country origin. There are only two countries for this, US and Australia.

My code that keeps returning a syntax error is below. Thank you everyone in advance for your insight.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Mobile Number],"")),
      IF([Country Origin] = "US"
     ,TEXT([Mobile Number],"(000) 000-0000"),
     IF([Country Origin] = "Australia"
        ,TEXT([Mobile Number],"+61 (00) 0000-0000"),
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that there are some problems with parentheses in your formula.

Try this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Mobile Number]),"", IF([Country Origin] = "US", TEXT([Mobile Number],"(000) 000-0000"), IF([Country Origin] = "Australia", TEXT([Mobile Number],"+61 (00) 0000-0000"),"")))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.